# Optimum PermSize for a Grails application deployed on tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I downloaded source code from an opensource clinic management system [CMS] (http://cms.mobigator.com/pages/index.asp?lang=en), It is developed in Grails. I was able to build it successfully, created war and deployed war on Tomcat Server. but every time the application through permgerm error. I increased the permsize to 1G.
Will that be enough for the application.?
Secondly I am a Java Programmer, where I can start learning Grails framework?
I am finding difficulty understanding the code and applying changes

Comment: One question per question :)

Comment: You can start learning Grails via their offical site : http://grails.org/doc/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the application in question however there are some [suggestions](http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/performanceTuning.html) for tuning your Tomcat memory settings for Grails.

I personally have found that learning Grails from the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) is the best approach. Read it slowly and from beginning to end. There is a lot to understand but if you take your time you will have a great understanding of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Increased permgen to 1G?

`PermGen` is where classes are loaded make sure you set that considering your libraries included in the project.

You must set the permgen near 256-384 only if the used libraries are not too much.

A good way change mem config is in apache/bin/catalina.sh

add:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
```

Some Info:

```
  -Xms512m -Xmx1024m`     > heap min and max
    -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m > permgen min and max
```

Comment: What will be the drawbacks of increasing PermGen size to 1G?

Comment: what are the drawbacks of wasting ram? I meant use 1G only when you need 1G try using some visualVM tools to know how much your app need permgen or heap space.